# homebrew composer failed to load php xdebug

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew, xdebug

I upgraded my homebrew xdebug from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7, without checking i brew cleanup the previous version, but when i tried to run composer it outputs the following error.

```
   Failed loading /usr/local/Cellar/php54-xdebug/2.2.6/xdebug.so: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54-xdebug/2.2.6/xdebug.so, 9): image not found
```

OS: Mountain Lion, the composer and php54-xdebug are installed via homebrew.

I tried downgrading xdebug but version 2.2.6 is not available in the brew versions php54-xdebug command. [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

composer version is 1.0.0-alpha9

Comment: You can try `brew install --build-from-source php71-xdebug` from this issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2518

Answer (score 4):

It took me awhile to find it, the xdebug extension that is bound to the php.ini file was not updated after the brew upgrade, update the version inside the ext-xdebug.ini from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-apc.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
```